# Binary Search Tree malloc not giving enough memory for following nodes

Tags: c, memory, malloc, binary-search-tree

I've come up with a problem where I do not give enough memory to my node after the first one when I do, for example, `firstNode = (node)malloc(sizeof(node))`.
The following is the structure of *node and the insert function that uses the malloc function.

```
typedef struct treeNode *node;

struct treeNode {
    node left;
    node right;
    int data;
};

node firstN;
node secondN;

node insert(int a, node t){
    if(t==NULL){
        t = (node)malloc(sizeof(node));
        t->data = a;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if(a < t->data){
            t->left = insert(a, t->left);
        }else if(a > t->data){
            t->right = insert(a, t->right);
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Here is the main() where I tested the inserting process with malloc (I did not use the insert function defined above, because I was still testing line by line in the main).

```
firstN=(node)malloc(sizeof(node)*10);
firstN->data=1;
firstN->right=NULL;
firstN->left=NULL;
firstN->right=(node)malloc(sizeof(node)*10);
```

Interesting thing for me is that while the above works, just normally doing (node)malloc(sizeof(node)) (without the multiply by 10) does not work for the second instance, firstN->right.

I wonder why the code is not giving enough memory, if that is the correct case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
t = (node)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

is wrong, you're not allocating enough memory to hold the structure, just the pointer to it since `node` is an alias for "pointer to `struct treeNode`".

You need:

```
t = malloc(sizeof *t);
```

Notice how that is way simpler? [The cast is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), so it should be removed. And the size was wrong, so let's have the compiler compute it.

For many (many) allocations where you're storing the result in some pointer `p`, the value of `sizeof *p` is the proper argument to `malloc()`. This doesn't hold if you're allocating *arrays* of course, then it's often `n * sizeof *p` for some expression `n`.

Also, using `typedef` to hide pointers is generally a bad idea in C, since the pointers *matter* and it quickly becomes confusing.

Comment: oh wow that does look way way simpler. thanks a lot. but here is a follow up question, if you don't mind. Why can't we then do malloc(sizeof *node) instead? I tried this, and it didn't work. Also, I just tried compiling without the casting, and it would work unfortunately, saying that void * is not of type node.. :(

Comment: @meany If the compiler complains about a missing cast, you're compiling as C++ instead of C. You can't write `malloc(sizeof *node)`, because `node` is a type, and not a pointer that you could dereference (although, the pointer `n` is _not_ dereferenced in `malloc(sizeof *n)`, the expression `*n` therein only serves to determine the type, and from that the required size).

Comment: If it doesn't compile without the cast, then you're not using a C compiler. And you can't do `sizeof *node` because `*node` is not a valid expression because `node` is a type, not a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct treeNode {
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
    int data;
}node;

node *firstN;
node *secondN;

node *insert(int a, node *t){
    if(t==NULL){
        t = malloc(sizeof(node));
        t->data = a;
        t->left = NULL;
        t->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if(a < t->data){
            t->left = insert(a, t->left);
        }else if(a > t->data){
            t->right = insert(a, t->right);
        }
    }
    return t;
}

int main(void) {

    firstN = malloc(sizeof(node)); /* allocating ROOT Node */
    firstN->data = 1;
    firstN->right = NULL;
    firstN->left = NULL;

    /* why are you allocating RIGHT, it will automatically be allocated when you insert Node */
    //firstN->right = (node)malloc(sizeof(node)*10);
}
```